# Why is this ilmerge command not working?

Tags: c#, ilmerge

Ive got this ilMerge command:

```
"C:\Repositories\trunk\utilities\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /closed /target:winexe /ndebug /out:C:\TestReferences\TestReferences_Merged.exe "C:\TestReferences\TestReferences\bin\Release\TestReferences.exe"
```

And there are no references but even when there are the compiled .exe just does not run. Even though this command works on all my other projects....

Comment: No exception?  Just *nothing* when you run it?

Comment: @Dave I had something similar, no output just exits

Answer (score 1):

Is this a WPF application?  According to the [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) site, they can't merge WPF assemblies.

Comment: That was my impression too, but I can't find any mention of WPF one way or the other on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/people/mbarnett/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fpeople%2Fmbarnett%2Filmerge.aspx#!ilmerge or in the docs at https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge/blob/master/ilmerge-manual.md.

Comment: My answer is 7 years old, so things may have changed since then.  The old site: https://web.archive.org/web/20110502155412/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx has it on the front page, but the latest version was published in 2014, so maybe they fixed it.